# DateFormat system.currenttimemillis()

Tags: android-studio, date-format

As the date is in Milli second format,  How do i convert it to have a DD/MM/YY format??

```
Long Ldate = System.currentTimeMillis();
String date = Ldate.toString();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please use this code. This will help you.

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
SimpleDateFormat dayTime = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
String str = dayTime.format(new Date(time));
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please ask for another problem. I am always ready.

Comment: i do have another problem but it is not related to this and is something more big haha. It is more of android studio things

Comment: @bear1030: why you did not suggested daytime.format(new Date());